# how to make a value in function a property of a service angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a function called showPosition which is called by getLocation. Now i need to make the *position.coords.latitude* and *position.coords.longitude* as part of my service restaurants. But i have no idea how to do it.

Here is the code for *showPosition*

```
function showPosition(position) {

    $.getJSON("http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/geoposition/search?apikey=RyDbyMAwF4gdnPcabtlH0roIGcmAXaqX&q=" + position.coords.latitude + '%2C' + position.coords.longitude, function(data) {

        jsonObject = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
        console.log(jsonObject);
        decodedJSON = JSON.parse(jsonObject);


        restaurants.locationOfTheUser = 'You are at' + decodedJSON['EnglishName'] + 'at latitude:' +  position.coords.latitude + 'and longitude' +  
        position.coords.longitude + ' ';
      //This does not work.

        restaurants.restaurantsNearTheUser = restaurants.names[locationOfTheUser];
        alert(locationOfTheUser);
    });
}
```

and here is the code for getLocation

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        alert( "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}
```

Both the showPosition and getLocation are defined in the service.

This is the service

```
myApp.factory('restaurants', function() {
  var restaurants = {};
  var jsonObject, decodedJSON, locationOfTheUser;
  restaurants.names = {
    'Dr Rajkumar Ward': [
      '1947 Restaurant',
      'Malleshwaram Dose Corner',
      'Veena Stores',
      'Punjab Mail',
      'Hallimane Restaurant'
    ],
    'Yelahanka': [
      'Aahaar Dosas',
      'Onesta Yelahanka',
      'Hotel Amrapali Andhra Style',
      'Gokul Veg',
      'Beijing Bites'
    ],
    'Sampangiram Nagar' : [
    'New Krishna Bhavan',
    'The GreenPath Organic State',
     'Hotel Savi International',
     'RR Biriyani',
     'Sangeet Family Restaurant & Bar',
    ],
  };
```

```
  restaurants.getLocation = function() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      } else {
          alert( "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
      }
  }

  console.log(restaurants.getLocation);
  function showPosition(position) {        
    $.getJSON("http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/geoposition/search?apikey=RyDbyMAwF4gdnPcabtlH0roIGcmAXaqX&q=" + position.coords.latitude + '%2C' + position.coords.longitude, function(data) {

      jsonObject = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
      console.log(jsonObject);
      decodedJSON = JSON.parse(jsonObject);


      restaurants.locationOfTheUser = 'You are at' + decodedJSON['EnglishName'] + 'at latitude:' +  position.coords.latitude + 'and longitude' +  
              position.coords.longitude + ' ';
      restaurants.restaurantsNearTheUser = restaurants.names[decodedJSON['EnglishName']];
      alert(restaurants.restaurantsNearTheUser);
    });
  }

  return restaurants;
});//service ends
```

Comment: How the `restaurants` service is the same one that has `getLocation` and `showPosition` or different one? can you add how it is declared?

Comment: Ah, why you used `$.getJSON`(jQuery ajax) to make http call? you should use `$http` service.

Comment: Use the AngularJS [$http Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for HTTP GET requests. AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc..

Comment: @yazantahhan yes there are in the same service named restaurants